# Element-by-element division in pandas dataframe with "/"?

Tags: python, pandas

Would be great to understand how this actually work.  Perhaps there is something in Python/Pandas that I don't quite understand.

I have a dataframe (price data) and would like to calculate the returns.  Rows are the stocks while columns are the dates.

For simplicity, I have created the prices with some random numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_price = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
df_ret = df_price.iloc[:,1:]/df_price.iloc[:,:-1]-1
```

There are two things are find it strange here:

1. My numerator and denominator are both 10 x 9.  Why the output is a 10 x 10 with the first column being nans.
2. Why the results are all 0 besides the first columns being nans.  i.e. why the calculation didn't perform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we do the div, we need to consider the `index` and `columns` for both `df_price[:,1:]` and `df_price.iloc[:,:-1]`, matched firstly, so we need to add the `.values` to remove the index and column match first, then the output will perform what we expected.

```
df_ret = df_price.iloc[:,1:]/df_price.iloc[:,:-1].values-1
```

Example

```
s=pd.Series([2,4,6])
s.iloc[1:]/s.iloc[:-1]
Out[54]: 
0    NaN # here the index s.iloc[:-1] included
1    1.0
2    NaN # here the index s.iloc[1:] included
dtype: float64
```

From above we can say , the pandas object , match the index first , and more like a `outer` match.